# How to launch WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I want to launch `WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp` located in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\InputApp_cw5n1h2txyewy`. To be clear, I don't want to display the touch-keyboard, I just need this particular process to be running. Is there a way to achieve that? Using .NET extensions is acceptable, but not preferred.

I want to do this to add a StateChangedWatcher at startup, but the process does not yet exist at startup and needs to be started manually for this to work right now.
Also, addding this to startup manually does not launch it, neither does simply trying to execute this. Are there any parameters it needs to be launched with?

Comment: Why do you want a process to be running, but don’t want it to display UI?

Comment: @kennyzx Added an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To be clear, I don't want to display the touch-keyboard, I just need this particular process to be running. Is there a way to achieve that?

You will find `AppxManifest.xml` in the `C:\Windows\SystemApps\InputApp_cw5n1h2txyewy` folder. And there is `windows.protocol` name in it. In other words, you could launch it with [`Windows.System.Launcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher)

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
  <uap:Protocol Name="ms-inputapp" DesiredView="useMinimum">
    <uap:DisplayName>Input App</uap:DisplayName>
  </uap:Protocol>
</uap:Extension>
```

**Usage**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.DesiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum;
    var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-inputapp:"), options);
}
```

Comment: Hello! It seems like this method only works as long as the touch-keyboard has already been used. If I restart my device, and then try this method without launching they touch-keyboard beforehand, it will launch a blue window that does nothing and the process stops if I close it.